# SQL update with hard-coded column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help creating a SQL update for the following example (with sample data):

Table 1:  DETAILTRAN
Structure: VENDOR CHAR(10), EMPLOYEE CHAR(10), WEEK INT

```
VENDOR   EMPLOYEE      WEEK
VEN01       EMP01         1
VEN01       EMP01         1
VEN02       EMP03         1
VEN03       EMP02         1
VEN01       EMP01         2
VEN01       EMP01         2
VEN01       EMP03         2
VEN03       EMP02         2
VEN02       EMP01         3
VEN02       EMP01         3
VEN02       EMP03         3
VEN03       EMP03         3
```

Table 2: SUMMARTRAN (that needs to be updated)

Structure: WEEK01 INT, WEEK02 INT, WEEK03 INT, VENDOR CHAR(10), EMPLOYEE CHAR(10)
The results of SQL Update this table (SUMMARTRAN) should look like this:

```
WEEK01     WEEK02    WEEK03    VENDOR   EMPLOYEE
2          3         0         VEN01
1          0         3         VEN02
1          1         1         VEN03
2          2         2                  EMP01
1          1         0                  EMP02
1          1         2                  EMP03
```

Comment: Are you looking to add new records or update existing ones?

Comment: @DanBracuk To add new records to the empty table. That is, I thought I would truncate the SUMMARTRAN first and then add records from the DETAILTRAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this using `grouping sets` and conditional aggregation:

```
select vendor, employee,
       sum(case when week = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as week01,
       sum(case when week = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as week02,
       sum(case when week = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as week03
from DETAILTRAN
group by grouping sets ((vendor), (employee));
```

You can incorporate this into an `insert`, statement for `summartran`:

```
insert into summertran(vendor, employee, week01, week02, week03)
    select vendor, employee,
           sum(case when week = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as week01,
           sum(case when week = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as week02,
           sum(case when week = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as week03
    from DETAILTRAN
    group by grouping sets ((vendor), (employee));
```

Comment: Never heard of  `Grouping set`. Thanks for sharing : ) Here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d977/14)

Comment: Gordon, Thank you. I have never heard of grouping set either (but I am a SQL newbie).   VR46, thank you for the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with VENDOR as
(
select isnull(count(case when WEEK = 1 then WEEK end),0) WEEK01,
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 2 then WEEK end),0) WEEK02 ,  
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 3 then WEEK end),0) WEEK03 ,
VENDOR
from DETAILTRAN 
group by VENDOR
),EMPLOYEE as
(
select isnull(count(case when WEEK = 1 then WEEK end),0) WEEK01,
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 2 then WEEK end),0) WEEK02 ,  
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 3 then WEEK end),0) WEEK03 ,
EMPLOYEE
from DETAILTRAN 
group by EMPLOYEE
)
select WEEK01, WEEK02, WEEK03, VENDOR, EMPLOYEE = '' from VENDOR 
union all
select WEEK01, WEEK02, WEEK03, VENDOR='', EMPLOYEE from EMPLOYEE
```

- [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d977/9)

To update the result to `SUMMARTRAN` table use this

```
with VENDOR as
(
select isnull(count(case when WEEK = 1 then WEEK end),0) WEEK01,
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 2 then WEEK end),0) WEEK02 ,  
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 3 then WEEK end),0) WEEK03 ,
VENDOR
from DETAILTRAN 
group by VENDOR
),EMPLOYEE as
(
select isnull(count(case when WEEK = 1 then WEEK end),0) WEEK01,
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 2 then WEEK end),0) WEEK02 ,  
       isnull(count(case when WEEK = 3 then WEEK end),0) WEEK03 ,
EMPLOYEE
from DETAILTRAN 
group by EMPLOYEE
)
insert into  SUMMARTRAN (WEEK01, WEEK02, WEEK03, VENDOR, EMPLOYEE)
select WEEK01, WEEK02, WEEK03, VENDOR, EMPLOYEE = '' from VENDOR 
union all
select WEEK01, WEEK02, WEEK03, VENDOR='', EMPLOYEE from EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: VR46, first, thank you.  What I don't understand is where in your code is update of the second table (SUMMARTRAN)?

Comment: **Insert** is what i meant by saying update. I have added `insert into..` in  second query

Comment: VR46, thank you very much.  Now I just need to figure which of the above approaches is faster.

Comment: @Hidalgo - without any doubt Gordan's approach will be faster

Comment: VR46, thank you.  But your example is a good learning for me.
And I am very impressed how you can quickly create a SQL Fiddle demo (need to learn this tool too).